# Property 'xxx' does not exist on type 'string' when index signature has the property type

Tags: typescript, interface

I'd appreciate some help on the following error.
I have an interface defined as:

```
export interface HandleOpenEvent {
  tooltipPayload: {
    dataKey: string;
    name: string;
    payload: {
      name: string;
      [id: string]: { title: string } | string;
    };
  }[];
}
```

Notice that I have `title` property defined. However, When I try to access the `title` property like this

```
const handleOpen = (e: HandleOpenEvent) => {
    const levelID = e.tooltipPayload[0].name;

    console.log(e.tooltipPayload[0].payload[levelID].title) //this throw the error below


    console.log(e.tooltipPayload[0].payload.name) //this works
```

I got an error:

```
Property 'title' does not exist on type 'string | { title: string; }'.
  Property 'title' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

I tried narrowing as suggested in some posts, but that did not fix the error.

```
//narrowing did not work here
   if (typeof e.tooltipPayload[0].payload[levelID] != "string") {
      setDetailKey(e.tooltipPayload[0].payload[levelID].title);
    }
```

I search on Stackoverflow and google with various keywords but couldn't find a relevant explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const levelPayload = e.tooltipPayload[0].payload[levelID]
if(typeof levelPayload === 'object') {
   levelPayload.title
}
```

though if possible I'd suggest to rethink the 'payload' interface. For example maybe this could be better

```
type LevelId = string
interface Payload {
   name: string
   levels: Record<LevelId, Level>
}
interface Level {
   title: string
}
```

then there won't be ambiguity and this won't create type error

```
...payload.levels[levelId]?.title
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution works like magic! I cannot fathom how assigning an intermediate variable could solve this issue. Any idea why your solution works? Thanks again

Comment: Because `.payload[levelID]` is dynamic operation and typescript isn't yet able to infer that it will result in same value when called multiple times. Maybe in future we'll see improvement. But regardless - it's still good idea to assign to intermediate variable as it results in better readability.